# What are the Mirror Universe Borg like?

Tags: star-trek, borg, mirror-universe

Is there any canon reference to the **Mirror Universe Borg** that would explain more about them?

I've tried searching on my own and haven't found anything.

Comment: Speaking of [sexy borg cosplay](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/4a/85/60/4a856025524d365c87cbc3a83e9408c8.jpg)....

Comment: the Amish could be mirror Borg all along...

Comment: They go around being very nice to people and handing out technology like Santa Claus at Christmas. *"We are the Borg. We will add our technological and biological distinctiveness to your own. Our culture will adapt to serve you. Resistance is futile."*

Comment: They're a "no means no" advocacy group.

Comment: They're all individualist Ayn Rand worshippers: "Assimilate the intruder." "Shut up! You aren't the boss of me, you collectivist! You do it!" "Negative, insufficient profit motive."

Comment: "Compliance is voluntary."

Comment: Of interest, according to https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Mirror: "Jean-Luc Picard remarks on the irony that the mirror universe's inhabitants have never encountered Q or the Borg, the only powers he can think of that might actually have outmatched and humbled them."

Answer (score 10):

### Main Canon

Within the main Trek Series and films, there's zero indication of a Mirror Universe Borg society. It probably exists, but we simply don't get to see it.

### EU Canon.

In the weird and wacky [EU Canon](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_(mirror)), **the Mirror Universe Borg are presided over by a [Borg *King*](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Worst_of_Both_Worlds)**.

> *Deep in the bowels of his mechanical hive, shielded by overlapping
> layers of multigenerative security grids, the Borg king detected a
> disturbance spreading through the Collective, interfering with the
> proper operation of the ship. Ego buffers protected the king from the
> alien pathogen, which was rapidly overcoming the various measures
> installed to protect the ship’s systems from contamination. The king
> noted that the mysterious pathogen had already infected the vinculum
> linking the vessel’s various drones and unimatrixes. Interesting, he
> mused.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Mirror Universe - Glass Empires.](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Worst_of_Both_Worlds)</sup></sub>

**They travel around in [massive 10Km wide cubes](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Through_a_Glass,_Darkly).**

> *Mirror Universe Borg are even worse than their Federation Universe
> counterparts. They possess the same hive mind, the same techniques of
> assimilation, the same superior technology — but the resemblance ends there. Where the Federation Borg are zombie-like automatons, Mirror Borg are more proactively aggressive. Any time they sense an intruder aboard one of their ships, they attack with every
> resource at their command — they won’t ignore an unknown invader just
> because he’s “not interfering” with them.*
>
> *They’re also much quicker
> than Federation Borg. Thanks to developments in Borg nanoprobes and
> other technologies, Mirror Borg lack the stiff-legged gait and awkward
> motion of Federation Borg. With their skeleton and musculature
> enhanced by Borg technology, they move very quickly. Drawing a bead on
> them with a disruptor, or avoiding their hand-to-hand attacks, often
> becomes an impossible exercise. Their cubes are larger, as well — 10
> kilometers on a side, or more — and equipped with incredibly powerful
> weapons capable of destroying a Vor’cha-class ship with a single
> blast.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Through a Glass, Darkly (RPG Module)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_Universe_(Decipher))</sup></sub>

Aside from that, their society is pretty similar to Main Universe Borg.

Comment: darn :/ but thanks for the response I was somewhat hoping they would have been more of like a parasite where instead of wires they would have like worm bodies comeing off of them or something  rather than mechanical like in the main universe thanks again :)

Comment: @TheAnswer - What's intriguing is that despite the relative ease with which one can access the mirror universe, the two Borgs don't seem to have joined forces.

Comment: I was hoping that the mirror borg were peaceful.

Comment: @Amaranth - "**Resistance to our gift baskets is futile.", "We are the Borg, you will be assisted.", "Lower your shields and prepare for hugs and cuddles"**.

Comment: Drones lurk in the shadows and attack-hug any passers by.

Comment: @Valorum The Borg being Borg, the more likely outcome would be that each universe's collective would try to assimilate the other. (All of a sudden I'm interested in mirror universe Q, Douwd and Voth.)

Comment: @Hans - There are no mirror universe Q

Comment: Are mirror universe bees also led by a king!

Comment: EU Canon responses are acceptable

Comment: @1252748 - Mirror universe me probably 0 rep and thinks that Star Trek is "pretty boring".

Comment: @Valorum I assume that's established in one of the many EU books. A pity, really. I think I'd like either a thorougly respectable or a completely vile Q.

Comment: @TheAnswer You're getting them mixed up with the [Go'auld](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Goa%27uld) from Stargate.

Comment: Makes sense if you think that it was Q who introduced the Federation to the Borg to teach Picard a lesson...

Comment: @colmde - If he hadn't done so, the Federation would have been assimilated a few years later.