# Do Borg have different collectives depending on which reality they exist in, or are all Borg across all realities part of the same collective?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, borg, parallel-universe

[Similar, but not what I'm after.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144957/what-are-the-mirror-universe-borg-like)

In TNG *Parallels*, one of the alternate Enterprises consists of a Riker who claims that:

> The Borg are everywhere!

So there's Borg in at least two universes, probably more. Are they same the hive mind, or different?

As a concrete example, if a cube tried to beam up a drone during an ion storm <s>over a planet refusing to give them Dilithium Crystals</s> (ala TOS *Mirror Mirror*) and the drone swapped realities, would the Borg shrug it off like "meh" or would they be more alarmed, wondering why the heck they can't hear the drone despite the fact he's *right there*?

**Edit**: I understand that in the question I linked that in the EU, the Borg are *physically* different, and act differently. This makes sense as they are operating in a different reality, but still doesn't address the question of whether they're connected to all the other Borg.

Comment: I'd imagine that they would try to integrate a "foreign" drone if they came across one. Like they tried to integrate the advanced drone seen in Voyager

Comment: @Valorum, for sure. My question is whether or not the drone is even "foreign" to start with

Comment: Being interconnected across all realities would make them unstoppable. Just transfer shield frequencies and access codes from a reality where they have already defeated the Federation to a reality where they haven't.

Comment: Do you mean inter-connected, as in linked at more or less all times across multiple realities? Or do you mean compatible, as in, a drone from one reality could be used seamlessly in another by a "different" collective? Title and body of your question seem to differ on that. And the answers to both would probably be quite different.

Comment: @Kakturus, edited title, so I hope it's clearer. I'm trying to get at if there is such a thing as a "different" collective, or if it's all one massive collective.

Comment: This makes me wonder if the Borg from one universe would try to assimilate the Borg in the other universe if they are not of the same hive/collective. Borg_A to Borg_B: "Resistance is futile. You will be assimilated." Borg_B's reply: "Bull s***, you will be assimilated!"

Comment: @GridAlien I think the Borg would be intellgent enough to understand what the other borg are thinking, they also would be smart enough to know that they are in a alternate reality/timeline/universe.

Comment: Given that one can upload a virus to disrupt or even to kill the borg in one reality my feeling, though not supported by any evidence, is that each reality's Borg Collective are separate entities. 

To be the SAME entity across all space-time, would suggest trans-warp conduits are also time travel conduits, and I doubt there's canon evidence of that.

Answer (score 1):

The Borg are not the same hive mind across multiple universes.  We know this because of the mechanics of the physical layer of their "internet."  They maintain the hive mind via transwarp communications (apparently rather faster than subspace).  Transwarp is not multi-dimensional.

As far as your sub-question whether they could instantly merge and communicate with Borg from other dimensions, not likely.  We know from episode Best of Both Worlds Part 2 that the Borg network is encrypted.  All modern computer encryption is based on random number generators (of various types).  These are potentially sensitive enough to be different across universes.  A true random number generator based encryption would be different if even a few molecules in the room where the number was generated were moved.  This means if the new universe split off a microsecond ago, they might be the same.  But if there were any noticeable changes, the encryption would be different.  On the other hand, if all the Borg used the same seed for a psuedo-random number long ago, then perhaps they would all have same encryption.  But then again, they probably would have been hacked a long time ago in that case.
However, that math is based on real science, not show canon.

Ref for communications: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transwarp

Ref for encryption: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ddns/2019/2545123/

Comment: There are some very bold statements here but precious little by way of evidence to back them up

Comment: Perhaps bold, but I do cite my sources, which offer what little evidence exists on the subject.

Comment: So, yes, if the alternate dimension retained the same RNG sequence of Borgnet encryption,

Comment: @SillybutTrue I've been doing a bit of research on that question, and will add info to the answer.